Are there any sane ways to make or explore the properties of FOOF (dioxygen difluoride)?
FOOF (dioxygen difluoride) is one of the most insanely dangerous chemicals ever discovered (see this old question on its properties), more dangerous even than chlorine trifluoride (which, amazingly, is manufactured and used: see this answer).
One of the original ways to make it was to subject a gaseous mixture of oxygen and fluorine to 700 °C while flowing rapidly down a heated tube and capturing the product by cooling with liquid oxygen, which does not sound like a practical or safe approach to me.
Are there better ways to create enough FOOF to enable study of its properties or reactivity? And are there any "useful" reactions it could be used for?
PS OK I'm prompted to ask because there is a recent youtube video which deserves an answer here. Amazingly by Explosions&fire but clearly not done in his shed as he was still alive to post the video.

Possibly computationally  ;-)

With various molecular beam techniques I'm not sure you particularly need to make "enough" beyond what is transiently present.

IMO, that video is the best professional video Ex&F has ever produced considering that Tom doesn't consider his content scientific and more towards crapposting. I would consider the video on the same level as Veritasium's latest Thermite video :)

Well, some brave souls used it to make PuF6. If you already work on plutonium, then FOOF is no biggie, I guess https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00321a056

https://srd.nist.gov/jpcrdreprint/1.555830.pdf https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/dioxygen-difluoride https://edu.rsc.org/magnificent-molecules/dioxygen-difluoride/3010858.article

Just reiterating Derel Lowe's concise explanation: https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/things-i-won-t-work-dioxygen-difluoride

I'd be interested to know the reasons for downvotes. It isn't a dupe as it is asking a question that has not been asked before. It isn't asking for dangerous advice that people might experiment at home. And it isn't frivolous. There is a serious answer.

Well, it kinda pains me, because I like this topic and we could use some fun, but you're shooting yourself in the foot with "sane ways", "better ways", "practical or safe". You need to be specific. Safety is relative, definitely if you work with inherently dangerous things.

I did some research and likely "safest" approach is mixing liquid F2 and O2 and using strong UV lamp on them. Is it actually safe? I don't think so and not being it the same building would be reasonable, but what else would you expect?

What are the limits of these extreme compounds? Can FOOOF exist in sufficiently low temperatures?

@SidharthGhoshal Even FOOOOOOF likely does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexaoxygen_difluoride

It can be done in relative safety by an experienced lab using fairly conventional equipment
The route that works in relative safety is to zap a mixture of liquid oxygen and liquid fluorine with strong UV light at low temperatures.
This is not, it seems, particularly dangerous or risky if the lab is used to handling fluorine.
We know this because YouTuber Explosions&Fire recorded it being done. Not using his normal technique of attempting it in his garden shed (often for the purposes of both fun and chemical education) but because he was invited to one of the small number of professional labs equipped to do risky stuff with fluorine. The Hasenstab-Riedel Group at the Free University of Berlin are experts in halogen chemistry, particularly involving fluorine.
The group have experience in handling fluorine using what is largely conventional Schlenk equipment modified to handle fluorine (so metal, not glass, piping).
For the particular reaction that generated macroscopic amounts of FOOF they used some fairly standard techniques. They used reaction vessels made of a specific fluoropolymer that can resist fluorine to condense mL amounts of liquid fluorine and liquid oxygen into the plastic container and then subjected the mixture to intense UV light from a mercury discharge lamp for 2hr. After removing the excess volatile gases, the solid FOOF remained in the polymer vessel as an orange solid (at liquid nitrogen temperatures).
The setup allows some experimentation with reactions. For example, condensing xenon into the tube at liquid nitrogen temperature and then slight warming shows the instant reaction that leads to xenon tetrafluoride very rapidly (despite the low temperatures).
A similar setup allows the direct reaction of FOOF with chlorine (again at very low temperatures). This gives the other nightmare fuel, chlorine trifluoride which can be seen as a yellow liquid.
All these reactions were conducted safely in macroscopic quantities in a specialist lab with the right level of experience in handling dangerous compounds (in particular, fluorine).
Since the reaction to create FOOF was repeatable and repeated and all the participants are still alive and not lacking their normal quota of fingers, I think we can conclude that "sane" ways of handling FOOF are available and practical.

Xenon tetrafluoride. Uh hm. "A chaste nun and a psychopathic serial killer fall in love."
